# Entity Framework detect internal relation cnages

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a model that looks like this (not exactly):

```
class Child
{
    public virtual Parent AssignedParent { get; set; }
} 

class Container 
{
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
   public Child ActiveChild { get; set; }
}
```

With other words: a container can have many active children, but at most only one is active. This is working just great.

But now I need to check if such a container has changed the activechild property. `DC.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` performs correctly, but if I get the entry with `DC.ChangeTracker.Entries()` I see it unchanged.
This property is not in the CurrentValues or OriginalValues collection, which looks ok, as it is a navigation property.

But how can I check if this one has changed or not?

Comment: What happens when you call `SaveChanges()`? Are the changes saved to the database or not? Why check the `ChangeTracker`? Did you encounter another problem and thought that there is an issue with change tracking?

Comment: Yes, they are saved. So somewhere, internally, this is tracked. But I don't know how to het to it.
I need to know if only a specific property is changed or anything else too. My type is rather complex (nested objects serialized to json in backing fields). So I would like to rely on EF not to traverse all properties in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ForeignKey property:

```
class Container
{
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ActiveChild")
    public int ActiveChildId { get; set; }
    public Child ActiveChild { get; set; }
}
```

Override the DbContext SaveChanges method:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        #region Auditing

        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                 .Where(e => e.Entity is IAuditInfo && e.State == EntityState.Modified))
        {

        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
        #endregion
    }
```

Instead of IAuditInfo you can check the type of specific class e.g. Container.
Your foreignKey - ActiveChildId should be present in entry.CurrentValues[] and entry.OldValues[].
A comparison on the ID should tell you is it has changed.

Comment: That looks good. I had no idea how to make that id directly visible in the entity. The only thing it that it tries to add a new table field for that. But an ActiveChild_id field was already generated to hold the foreign key in the background (which I was unale to access). If I add the ActiveChild_id property, it tries to add a ActiveChild_id1 field. Can I somehow convince it to use the existing one, so I don't need to migrate, as on table level there should nothing actually be changed.

Comment: By convention EF would auto generate a property corresponding to a foreign key, if you don't define it explicitly. You can add the foreign key property, like I defined, give it some different name. Then when you add a new migration it should drop the autogenerated one and add the one that you defined explicitly.